# Fetch user details with LDAP-AUTHENTICATION Node Module

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, ldap

I am facing an issue while fetching user's details from LDAP-Authentication Module.
I tried solve this issue in various way, but I didn't get any luck.

I am getting below issue -
LDAPError [ReferralError]: 0000202B: RefErr: DSID-031007F9, data 0, 1 access points
ref 1: 'example.com'

Code=>

```
const { authenticate } = require('ldap-authentication')
async function auth() {
  options = {
    ldapOpts: {
      url: 'ldap://localhost:3000',
    },
    userDn: 'onemail@gmail.com',
    userPassword: 'password',
    userSearchBase: 'cn=onemail,dc=gmail,dc=com',
    usernameAttribute: 'mail',
    username: 'onemail'
  }

  user = await authenticate(options).then(res=>{
      console.log("res =>",res)
  }).catch(err=>{
      console.log("err => ",err)
  })
  console.log("user=>",user)
}
auth()
```

Comment: The domain components (dc) set in `userSearchBase: 'cn=onemail,dc=gmail,dc=com'` implies that the FQDN of your server is 'gmail.com'. If the dc's don't match the domain name you got the error.

Answer (score 1):

A referral means "I can't help you but I know who can." That means the server you are connecting to is a domain controller, but not for the domain (the `userSearchBase`) you're asking for.

It looks like the error message is giving you the server name of the DC it's referring you to, so use that in your `url` instead.